# How to ensure long-term enterprise software stability with changing frameworks / things going out of support?

Tags: enterprise-architecture, dependency-management, enterprise-development

I work for the in-house IT department of one of the largest companies in my country.

The infrastructure and software systems are heavily based on Oracle Database.
Most core business processes and business logic is built using SQL and PL/SQL batch jobs, importing data into the database, transforming, consolidating, communicating via DB-links etc.
This system has been gradually built up for the last 30 years. It's a very homogenous system, which also has its advantages.

Now recently there has been a push to move towards different technologies, diversifying, and less reliance on Oracle (cost is one factor - we're hosting several hundred Enterprise Edition databases and thousands of Standard Editions).

However, one question often comes up:
Oracle database has been fairly stable and backwards compatible - how do we ensure the long-term stability (10 years+) of the system in a more heterogenous environment?
Say we have components A, B, C, D using a certain framework, hosted on a cloud somewhere.
What if the cloud provider drops support for the framework? What if component B and C are no longer compatible due to a breaking change?

I haven't heard a satisfying answer yet - basically the only answer I got so far was "we'll just have to rewrite it"

So I'm hoping to find out what strategies should be employed to prevent us from basically having to rewrite everything every 3 years.

Comment: I wonder. Would you argue that all of that 30 years old code is still used in it's full capability and supporting old use cases? And that it is efficient way to support new use cases?

Comment: In short: you can't. In our industry, change is the only constant.

Comment: @Euphoric Certainly not all of it. But for example one of the systems i work on hasn't really changed considerably since 2004. It has been tweaked and added upon, but the core mechanic is still the same.
Supporting new use-cases is a different manner of course, one of the challenges we face is talking to things outside of the Oracle "universe".

Comment: The *reason* companies pay Oracle (and the like) a lot of money is precisely because they provide continuity over decades, which is important for large businesses whose operations span decades. The first thing that will happen with "heterogenous frameworks", adopted mainly or wholly for cost reasons, is that in a couple of years the whole thing will be an unmaintainable thicket, because reproducing detailed knowledge of *all* the minor or fleeting technologies will not occur. There's no secret sauce where you get big-software functionality, for small-workshop prices.

Comment: I mean, you can mitigate the problem by restructuring code over time so that it doesn't depend directly on those libraries - but don't try to do it at once, have a strategy, do a small experiment, (re)assess, do it again. Maybe check out [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052) by Michael Feathers.

Answer (score 7):

The more you leverage *Other Peoples Work TM* the more your are at the whim of other people.

So there are four ways to handle this:

1. Pay a *Not Inconsequential Amount of Money* to develop and maintain 100% (or as near as possible) of everything in house. Keeping it current, working, bug free, and backward compatible is completely your own problem. At least you can change what you want (more or less).
2. Pay a *Not Inconsequential Amount of Money* to make a third party care enough about keeping that technology current, working, bug free, and backward compatible. Any changes you do want will likely cost an arm and a leg, and take a long time to be received. Rent lords like being paid, to not change things.
3. Pay a *Not Inconsequential Amount of Money* to keep some developers on to maintain that technology as part of a community effort, even if you don't need to make any changes for internal needs. Keeping it current, working, bug free, and backward compatible is your problem for the bits you care about. Oh and lots of arguments around stewardship. Warning though, you may be forced to take it all in house, or become rent lords for that technology.
4. Pay a *Not Inconsequential Amount of Money* to continually rebuild software as it dies on an old broken technology, and is reborn on a new technology. Also say hi to frequent retraining, and possible high people turn over as the 3 year old employee brought on for project unicorn is now working on the project dinosaur... Wait, was that a meteor?

---

In my mind figure out what mix of the above strategies work for your situation.

You will have to be clear to the business managers what this means for the bank balance, and future budgeting.

1. Large in house team, long term employees, time not delivering functional changes, to focus on operational and developmental changes.
2. Large vendor spending, slow moving new features, a medium-large support/operational crew to handle deployment and monitoring.
3. Small-Large team of developers working in a larger community of developers. Good will in the community has to be fostered, and earnt by performing civic responsibilities including delivering code to support competitors. There is a chance though that others will help you out too finding bugs, issues, solving problems, etc... Also code is not 100% under you own control, it may loose desired features, or be altered to cause some internal projects difficulties.
4. Large in house team/Frequent external contracts to produce new software. Frequent retraining, frequent employee turnover. Frequent decommissioning activities. Accessing data from older systems nigh impossible even with a data lake, alternately requires life-support crews to maintain the system moving this to an in house solution with a horrendous code/technology base. Prefer to use only for systems that are not record keeping, and are frivolous. Seriously this does not make for long term software.

---

Those new frameworks fall into bucket 3 or 4.

- unless there is a company willing to contract maintenance guarantees, and your willing to pay, then its a 2
- or its open source, and are willing to house the large team to maintain it in house, then its a 1.

Cloud based services are either 2 or 4. Probably 4 as I've yet to see a guarantee of service contract.

- Even just a raw instance is a 4 (sans a strict guaranteed contract), but at least it can be converted to an in house instance easily enough (a 1).

Oracle Database, that's a 2.

And all of your homegrown applications around it are in the 1 category.

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

- **Abstract dependencies** that can be reasonably abstracted, so you're prepared for needing to swap them out in the future.
- If you're relying on vendor support, **vet your vendors** and take a good look at their support contracts.
- If you don't want to deal with breaking changes, **don't blindly update major versions** of your dependencies. Beware vendor support lifetimes where relevant.
- As a general tip, if you want to minimize bugs, **avoid adopting new major versions immediately**. As time goes on, those releases tend to be finetuned and bugs get fixed with minor version updates.

---

### Frameworks vs libraries

> How to ensure long-term enterprise software stability with changing **frameworks** / things going out of support?

"Frameworks" is a potential red flag here. There's a difference between frameworks and libraries. Though there is some discussion as to exactly where the line is drawn of whether a given library is actually a framework, there is a general tendency.

Libraries are dependencies that add some functionality to your application. For good practice, these interfaces can and should be abstracted to ensure that you can swap out one library for another, without needing to change the contract itself.

Frameworks, however, are much harder to abstract. Often, this is because they provide a foundation for you to build (part of) your application on top of, and therefore they can't easily be removed.

In the end, whether implement something or not is a matter of **least effort**. What is going to take the least amount of time: abstracting the dependency, or the extra time it takes to change the non-abstracted dependency (also factoring in the odds of needing to change the dependency)?
Companies and stakeholders will always favor the least effort solution since this minimizes work hours and therefore development costs.

This is just my take on a definition of frameworks and libraries:

- If abstracting the dependency takes less effort than time it takes to swap the dependency when it's not abstracted, then it's a *library* and you should abstract it.
- If abstracting it take more effort than dealing with it's non-abstraction, or abstracting it means you lose out on some of the features that you'd otherwise be using, then it's a *framework* and it makes no sense to try and abstract it (why would you take the route of more effort and/or less benefit?)

As a simple example, think of the .Net framework (whether it's Framework or Core is irrelevant here, they're both frameworks). It's pretty much impossible to at the same time *use* it and remove it without any consequences to the codebase.

Simply put: frameworks generally require tighter coupling that make it harder to drop said framework from your codebase when it was built against that framework. That's generally unavoidable (assuming that the framework developers minimized coupling as best as they reasonably could).

---

### Versioning

> What if component B and C are no longer compatible due to a breaking change?

Any reasonable library/framework should make specific versions available even when newer versions are released. If B and C worked together in the past but have broken since one of them was updated, then revert that dependency back to the version that didn't break their interaction.

When done well, breaking changes between updates cause a shift in the major version number, where minor version updates don't cause breaking changes. But that very much depends on the vendor of the dependency.

If B and C do not need to directly interact with each other, then you may be able to write some custom inbetween logic that ensures the newest versions of B and C can still work together, but this is a cost/benefit issue: is the effort required worth having the newest version of B/C?

---

### Breaking changes

> So I'm hoping to find out what strategies should be employed to prevent us from basically having to rewrite everything every 3 years.

You're taking a bit of a contradictory stance.

- On the one hand, you want to rely on newly released updates for all your dependencies.
- But on the other hand, you want to avoid anything changing about your dependencies and how your code interacts with them.

You're going to have to decide where your priorities are.

If you don't update your dependencies (or at least stop doing so when an update breaks the codebase), then you don't have to change your codebase as it keeps working with the same tried and true dependencies.

If you do update your dependencies, then you are vulnerable to having to deal with any possible breaking changes. That's the inevitable consequence from updating your dependencies, especially for major version releases.

If this dependency entails vendor support, then you have to take their support lifetimes into account in case you decided to stick to a particular version. That's not something you can avoid, as the only other solution here would be to force your vendor to support your (now outdated) version indefinitely; which is their decision, not yours.

---

### Vendors

> Oracle database has been fairly stable and backwards compatible
>
> less reliance on Oracle (cost is one factor - we're hosting several hundred Enterprise Edition databases and thousands of Standard Editions)

Backwards compatibility takes effort, especially if it is maintained for a long time. This is part of the reason that the cost is so big, Oracle invests a lot of time and effort into figuring out how to improve their product while minimizing breaking changes across versions.

Also consider that if there were alternatives that were equal or better in every way (including cost, backwards compatibility and reliability), then Oracle wouldn't be charging you as much as they currently are.

From a library/framework developer's perspective, it's easier to have full freedom to implement any change without caring about them being a breaking change or not. Therefore, these vendors are generally cheaper as they can minimize effort and thus cost. However, this comes with a clear drawback for you as the customer: (possibly) having to deal with more breaking changes, which costs you more money in your own development effort.

As the adage goes, software can be built quickly, cheaply and robustly - but you can only pick two out of three.

Comment: Open source licenses *always* allow you to have a local copy of your current version. They even allow you to do maintenance on that copy. That is what open source in essence means.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Unfortunately no, It just means that you can see the code. The code itself is still under copyright. Fortunately most open source licences also give express and unrevocable permission to edit, and compile the code without fee or need for subsequent permission. Unfortunately some also require that you open source your own code in order to do so.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: _"Open source licenses always allow you to have a local copy of your current version."_ Predominantly so, but not exclusively so. They can't really prevent you from storing a local copy since you could've copy pasted the open source code at any point, but that's not the same as having permission to do so.

Comment: @Kain0_0, the term "open source" is commonly understood to refer to how the OSI (Open Source Initative) defined that term. Within that definition, you get additional freedoms besides just being able to read the source code. If you get the source code without permission to modify it, that is usually referred to as "source available". And I never said that the code is not under copyright, just that if something is open source, then the copyright license gives you additional permissions (possibly also with extra requirements on your code).

Comment: @Flater, can you give me an example of an open source license that doesn't allow you to have a local copy?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Yeah, its the `(possibly also with extra requirements on your code)` that is the issue here. Without accepting the extra requirements, which are not always about ensuring the openness of the source in question, the only right is the ability to read the source. I believe the GPL is an example of this: `Richard Stallman ... saying, "The GPL's domain does not spread by proximity or contact, only by deliberate inclusion of GPL-covered code in your program ...` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license?)

Comment: @Kain0_0, if you are not willing to accept the requirements that a license puts on you, there is no point in reading the source, because you can't use what you read for anything and moat likely the same restrictions already apply when you want to use the binaries..

Answer (score 0):

Usually in software books is written that you give what the clients need and not what they want. In real world is exactly opposite. 
Just because you have you have very stable old school platform, does not mean it is for the garbage. A new re-write has to be done very carefully, without a disruption in your business model.

I would recommend the following:
set up plan focusing on the following:

1. Security - does the new technology offers good security and trend with GDPR and HIPAA - Pick technology that out of the box has built in support for that.
2. Labor cost - what is the average cost for hiring or transition current developers for next 5 years with the new technology - Pick technology that is widely adapted and has good community trend around the region/country
3. Do a small prototype to export very small chunk of the old platform and survey users how they like the new platform.
4. Set a budget for at least 5 years transformation and see if or when the investment is ok to do. Timing is the the most important. Watch overall company performance and economy, watch competitors.
5. Establish benchmarks for the current system like stress test, load test, performance, user experience, etc.. Interview clients what they like and what they do not like.
6. Start with a very team of one or two individuals. make them work for three months. See what they discover and how the architecture is coming comparing paper design to real implementation. Start rolling into the team one person every so often but do not overdo it. Quantity doe snot lead to production.
7. Start sending old team members to online courses where they start learn the new technology without pushing them rapidly. Some of these people will need time to adapt to the new technology.
8. Use automation everywhere is possible only after manually the team had perform the same operations.
9. Plan for another 3 years plan after the platform goes live or three major releases. That is very important as people have to understand that just because you may go live, there will be changes.
10. Make sure you have budget to eliminate all of the old components or you will end up working with two technologies for a long time and the maintenance will be very expensive.